# How do I prevent my generic * { … } style from overriding parent tag

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent my generic `* { ... }` style from overriding parent tag? In the below example, I would like the `sssssssss` to be of the style `text-huge`

```css
.text-huge {
  font-size: 28px !important;
  color: green !important;
}

* {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p><span class="text-huge">line 1: aaaaaa<strong>sssssssss</strong>aaaaaaaa</span></p>
    <p>line 2</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I expect the `sssssssss` to be same font color and size as the rest of line 1

Comment: I would recomment to avoid using the `*` selector at all. In your case just set the default values (everything inside your `*` selector) to the `body` tag and overwrite it with stronger selectors (e.g. the `.text-huge` class you already have) wherever you need it. I also would recommend to stay away as far as possible from `!important`. Its the living devil in css.

Comment: @FabianSchöner, I would not say that `!important` is a living devil because it's very useful when modifying style through javascript. But also it's not ethical to use `!important` in primary styling of elements.

Comment: I would recommend reading about CSS specificity here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @Francisaskquestion i agree, overwriting inline styles from js which cant be changed by proper js configuration is one of the very few cases where i believe using `!important` is actually legit. I also stand by my statement as 90% of the `!important` usage on this planet is caused by lazyness or just not understanding how css works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the generic selector before, so everything else can be overridden without using `!important`.

```css
* {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: red;
}

.text-huge,
.text-huge * {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p><span class="text-huge">line 1: aaaaaa<strong>sssssssss</strong>aaaaaaaa</span></p>
    <p>line 2</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that the order has nothing to do here. You can keep `*` at the end, the main issue here is specificty and inheritance that you fixed by adding an extra rule.

Comment: You need this order if you don't want to use !important

Comment: no you don't : https://jsfiddle.net/58vLhw3s/

Answer (score 0):

Avoid use *, instead use inherit ! :) Gonna have a better performance.

```css
.text-huge {
  font-size: 28px !important;
  color: green !important;
}

.text-huge strong {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p><span class="text-huge">line 1: aaaaaa<strong>sssssssss</strong>aaaaaaaa</span></p>
    <p>line 2</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use children selector in your style.

```css
.text-huge,  .text-huge > * {
  font-size: 28px !important;
  color: green !important;
}

   

* {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p><span class="text-huge">line 1: aaaaaa<strong>sssssssss</strong>aaaaaaaa</span></p>
    <p>line 2</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Or you could create separate styling for the children of the `.text-huge` element.

```css
.text-huge {
  font-size: 28px !important;
  color: green !important;
}
.text-huge > * {
  font-size: 28px !important;
  color: green !important;
}

* {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <p><span class="text-huge">line 1: aaaaaa<strong>sssssssss</strong>aaaaaaaa</span></p>
    <p>line 2</p>
  </div>
</form>
```